# Does LVM store information about the volume group configuration in the filesystem (for example /etc)?

Tags: raid, lvm

I have an ubuntu 22.04 with software raid 5 and a LVM volume group with two logical volumes as "/home" and "/usr/local/src". I want to make a complete reinstall of the operating system without touching the data and configuration of the volume group, because I want to move the root volume from one ssd to another. So I want to know whether the configuration information of the volume group is stored in the root filesystem e.g. /etc, because then the volume group would be destroyed by the new installation. Does anyone know the answer to my question? Thank you very much!

Comment: The underlying configuration data for a volume group would be stored in a hidden meta area of the volume itself, much like how partition information is stored in an area that is (generally) unavailable to the user. You can test this by booting a live session of Ubuntu and mounting the volumes. This will confirm that the data will be intact and readable when accessed by a fresh operating system.

Answer (score 0):

It shouldn't be a problem. LVM is "self containing", all written on the disk which is used for the volumes, no extra info needed. I assume your `/` filesystem is not in the same volumegroup (or it's not even on LVM), that may cause issues.

The only info you loose, are the mount points, so you have to remember where to mount them.

You can test that easily. Boot up from an external USB device and you will see all your volumes (importatn commands: `pvs`, `vgs`, `lvs`)